# How to find a row that in a given table return maximize return and minimalize variance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame that consists of three columns (index, return, volatility) and five rows.
I would like to receive the index number that maximizes value of return AND minimizes value of volatility however the second condition is less important than first.

How can I receive that? I tried to apply method .rank() for both columns and then sort by them but effect was poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first select a subset of your dataframe containing the rows for which the `Return` is maximum and then use `idxmin()` to return the index of the first occurrence of the minimum `Volatility`.

Here is a dataframe example:

```
import pandas as pd
mydict = {'Return': [99999,1,1,99999, 809],
    'Volatility': [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
    }

 df = pd.DataFrame(mydict, columns = ['Return', 'Volatility'])
```

For this example, `df[df.Return==df.Return.max()]` yields:

> Return  Volatility
>   0    99999           1
>   3    99999           4

And `df[df.Return==df.Return.max()].Volatility.idxmin()` returns:

> 0

Which is the index associated with the `Volatility` of 1.